# Failed inserting more items in database using IPN, Paypal, add to cart

Tags: php, insert, paypal, shopping-cart, paypal-ipn

i adapted the ipn script to the buy now button and after that i include the add to cart button.

```
This is the buy now button:
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.company.develway.com/company_user?id=    <?php echo $id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo 'Premium Content for ' . $name; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="TV4SWL86EHYYQ">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>


This is add to cart button:
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it'sfast, free and secure!">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="finciucsergiu@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo 'Premium Content for ' . $name; ?>">
<input name="notify_url" value="http://www.company.develway.com/ipn.php" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Wid-001">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input name="notify_url" value="http://www.company.develway.com/ipn.php" type="hidden">
</form>
```

and this is the main part of the ipn file:

```
 if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$number_of_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];

$connection = mysql_connect("hhh", "fff", "lll");
$db_select = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO paid_companies(users_email, companies_id)
 VALUES('$payer_email', '$custom') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

}

AL works excellent with buy now and with add to cart if it is one item, but if i insert more than one in the database will be included just the last item. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have more than one item in the cart you have to loop through all items included in IPN to get all of the items in your database.

Check this out...

```
// Cart Items
$num_cart_items = isset($_POST['num_cart_items']) ? $_POST['num_cart_items'] : '';

$i = 1;
$cart_items = array();   
while(isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]))   
{   
    $item_number = isset($_POST['item_number' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_number' . $i] : '';   
    $item_name = isset($_POST['item_name' . $i]) ? $_POST['item_name' . $i] : '';   
    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity' . $i]) ? $_POST['quantity' . $i] : '';  
    $mc_gross = isset($_POST['mc_gross_' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_gross_' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_handling = isset($_POST['mc_handling' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_handling' . $i] : 0;
    $mc_shipping = isset($_POST['mc_shipping' . $i]) ? $_POST['mc_shipping' . $i] : 0;
    $custom = isset($_POST['custom' . $i]) ? $_POST['custom' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name1 = isset($_POST['option_name1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection1 = isset($_POST['option_selection1_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection1_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_name2 = isset($_POST['option_name2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name2_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection2 = isset($_POST['option_selection2_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection2_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name3 = isset($_POST['option_name3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name3_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection3 = isset($_POST['option_selection3_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection3_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name4 = isset($_POST['option_name4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name4_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection4 = isset($_POST['option_selection4_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection4_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name5 = isset($_POST['option_name5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name5_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection5 = isset($_POST['option_selection5_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection5_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name6 = isset($_POST['option_name6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name6_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection6 = isset($_POST['option_selection6_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection6_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name7 = isset($_POST['option_name7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name7_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection7 = isset($_POST['option_selection7_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection7_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name8 = isset($_POST['option_name8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name8_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection8 = isset($_POST['option_selection8_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection8_' . $i] : '';
    $option_name9 = isset($_POST['option_name9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_name9_' . $i] : '';   
    $option_selection9 = isset($_POST['option_selection9_' . $i]) ? $_POST['option_selection9_' . $i] : '';

    $btn_id = isset($_POST['btn_id' . $i]) ? $_POST['btn_id' . $i] : '';

    $current_item = array(   
                           'item_number' => $item_number,   
                           'item_name' => $item_name,   
                           'quantity' => $quantity, 
                           'mc_gross' => $mc_gross, 
                           'mc_handling' => $mc_handling, 
                           'mc_shipping' => $mc_shipping, 
                           'custom' => $custom,   
                           'option_name1' => $option_name1,   
                           'option_selection1' => $option_selection1,   
                           'option_name2' => $option_name2,   
                           'option_selection2' => $option_selection2, 
                           'option_name3' => $option_name3, 
                           'option_selection3' => $option_selection3, 
                           'option_name4' => $option_name4, 
                           'option_selection4' => $option_selection4, 
                           'option_name5' => $option_name5, 
                           'option_selection5' => $option_selection5, 
                           'option_name6' => $option_name6, 
                           'option_selection6' => $option_selection6, 
                           'option_name7' => $option_name7, 
                           'option_selection7' => $option_selection7, 
                           'option_name8' => $option_name8, 
                           'option_selection8' => $option_selection8, 
                           'option_name9' => $option_name9, 
                           'option_selection9' => $option_selection9, 
                           'btn_id' => $btn_id
                          );   

    array_push($cart_items, $current_item);   
    $i++;   
}
```

That will leave you with an array called $cart_items that contains all of your items.  You could add your database inserts into that loop I provided, or you could just use it to gather your cart items into $cart_items and then use that to work from.

Either way, you need to loop through the items.